# Using the "not" operator with find not working as expected

Tags: command-line, find

I have a directory "X" with a subdirectory called "lib", as well as other files and directories. This "lib" subdirectory in turn has a bunch of directories and files itself. I am trying to use `find` to get the pathnames to everything in directory X except anything that has to do with "lib".

So, I tried doing this:
`find -not -name "lib*"`

This will exclude the path `./lib` from the output, but will include everything in the lib directory itself i.e `lib/*`. I also tried:

`find -not -name "lib/*"`

but that gave me the same result

PS: I also tried `find -not -name lib*` but still got the same result

Comment: what is a bareword `-not` supposed to do? It is `-not expr` according to the manual. So I would interpret that as `find -not "lib*"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-name` option to `find` looks only at the individual file name, not the full path to the file. If you want to match on the full path, you need the `-path` option.

Some examples in a quick test tree I created:

```
$ find .
.
./b
./a
./lib
./lib/la
./lib/lb
```

What you are doing with `-name` (skips `lib` itself, but doesn't skip files within `lib` because it is only looking at the individual file names):

```
$ find . -not -name 'lib*'
.
./b
./a
./lib/la
./lib/lb
```

What you probably want:

```
$ find . -not -path './lib*'
.
./b
./a
```

Note that because `-path` looks at the **full** path, I now need to add the initial `./` prefix as well.